# data gets corrupted between c and python

Tags: python, cython, ctypes

I am trying to use Cython and `ctypes` to call a c library function using Python.
But the data bytes get corrupted somehow. Could someone please help to locate the issue?

`testCRC.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned char GetCalculatedCrc(const unsigned char* stream){
   printf("Stream is %x %x %x %x %x %x  %x\n",stream[0],stream[1],stream[2],stream[3],stream[4],stream[5],stream[6]);
   unsigned char dummy=0;
   return dummy;  
}
```

`wrapped.pyx`:

```
# Exposes a c function to python
def c_GetCalculatedCrc(const unsigned char*  stream):
     return GetCalculatedCrc(stream)
```

`test.py`:

```
  x_ba=(ctypes.c_ubyte *7)(*[0xD3,0xFF,0xF7,0x7F,0x00,0x00,0x41]) 
  x_ca=(ctypes.c_char * len(x_ba)).from_buffer(x_ba)
  y=c_GetCalculatedCrc(x_ca.value)
```

output:

> Stream is d3 ff f7 7f 0 0 5f  # expected
>   0xD3,0xFF,0xF7,0x7F,0x00,0x00,0x41

Solution:

1.
I had to update the cython to 0.29 to have the fix for the bug which was not allowing to use the typed memory.(read only problem).

2.
It worked passing x_ca.raw. But when x_ca.value was passed it threw error 'out of bound access.'

After the suggestions from @ead & @DavidW:

´.pyx´:

```
def c_GetCalculatedCrc(const unsigned char[:]  stream):
    # Exposes a c function to python
    print "received %s\n" %stream[6]
    return GetCalculatedCrc(&stream[0])
```

´test.py´:

```
x_ba=(ctypes.c_ubyte *8)(*[0x47,0xD3,0xFF,0xF7,0x7F,0x00,0x00,0x41])
x_ca=(ctypes.c_char * len(x_ba)).from_buffer(x_ba)
y=c_GetCalculatedCrc(x_ca.raw)
```

output:

> Stream is 47 d3 ff f7 7f 0 0 41

Comment: The problem is on the ctypes side - try `print(len(x_ca.value))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @DavidW the problem is your usage of `x_ca.value`: When `x_ca.value` is called, every time a new bytes-object is created (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._SimpleCData.value)) and memory is copied:

```
x_ca.value is x_ca.value
#False -> every time a new object is created
```

However, when the memory is copied, it handles `\0`-character as end of string (which is typical for C-strings), as can be seen in [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/487b73ab39c80157474821ef9083f51e0846bd62/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#L1237-L1245):

```
static PyObject *
CharArray_get_value(CDataObject *self, void *Py_UNUSED(ignored))
{
    Py_ssize_t i;
    char *ptr = self->b_ptr;
    for (i = 0; i < self->b_size; ++i)
        if (*ptr++ == '\0')
            break;
    return PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(self->b_ptr, i);
}
```

Thus the result of `x_ca.value` is a bytes object of length `4`, which **doesn't** share memory with `x_ca` - when you access `stream[6]` it leads to undefined behavior - anything could happen (also a crash).

---

So what can be done?

Normally, you just cannot have a pointer-argument in a `def`-function, but `char *` is an exception - a `bytes` object can be automatically converted to `char *`, which however doesn't happen via buffer protocol but via [`PyBytes_AsStringAndSize`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytes.html#c.PyBytes_AsStringAndSize).

This is the reason, why you cannot pass `x_ca` to `c_GetCalculatedCrc` as it is: `x_ca` implements the buffer protocol, but is not a `bytes`-object and thus there is no `PyBytes_AsStringAndSize`.

An alternative is to use typed memory view, which utilizes the buffer protocol, i.e.

```
%%cython 
def c_GetCalculatedCrc(const unsigned char[:] stream):
    print(stream[6]);
```

and now passing `x_ca` directly, with original length/content:

```
c_GetCalculatedCrc(x_ca)
# 65    as expected
```

---

Another alternative would be to pass `x_ca.raw` to function expecting `const unsigned char *` as argument, as has been pointed out by @DavidW in comments, which shares memory with `x_ca`. However I would prefer the typed memory views - they are safer than raw pointers and you would not run into surprisingly undefined behavior.

Comment: I think your buffer approach is better, but it also looks like `x_ca.raw` will get the full string. It does seem a strange choice for `.value` to stop at '\0' when knows the correct size

Comment: @DavidW You are right. Somewhere in the documentation they say: "The current memory block contents can be accessed (or changed) with the raw property; if you want to access it **as NUL terminated string**, use the value property:" Seen this way, it makes sense. But it is a pity there is no mention of it in the description of value-property.

Comment: 1.
I had to update the cython to 0.29 to have the fix for the bug which was not allowing to use the typed memory.(read only problem).
2.

It worked passing x_ca.raw. But when x_ca.value was passed it threw error 'out of bound access.'@DavidW..Thank you